# Why is the derivative of $e^{-x^2}$ equal to $-2xe^{-x^2}$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I was messing around with the derivatives and integrals of $e^{-x^{2}}$ on Desmos, and had mistakenly been integrating the function $\displaystyle{\displaylines{\int_{0}^{x} e^{-x^{2}}dt}}$ which coincidentally is equal to $\displaystyle{\displaylines{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{dt}e^{-x^{2}}}}$, but after realizing that this wasn't the actual integral, I tried to see how I could modify the actual integral $\displaystyle{\displaylines{\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt}}$ to result in this same curve as I mistakenly achieved earlier which I found with the below equation

$$
\displaystyle{\displaylines{-2e^{-x^{2}}\left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{n}}dt\right) = \frac{dx}{dt}e^{-x^{2}}}}
$$

Which it turns out that the limit $\displaystyle{\displaylines{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{n}}dt}}$ approaches the line $\displaystyle{\displaylines{y=x}}$, so the equation simplifies to:

$$
\displaystyle{\displaylines{-2xe^{-x^{2}} = \frac{dx}{dt}e^{-x^{2}}}}
$$

What I'm wondering is why multiplying $\displaystyle{\displaylines{e^{-x^{2}}}}$ by $\displaystyle{\displaylines{-2x}}$ would equal the derivative of the original function. I'd wager a guess that the answer might have to do with the property of $\displaystyle{\displaylines{e^{x}}}$ being its own derivative, but I have no clue where the $\displaystyle{\displaylines{-2}}$ comes from. Does anybody know why this might be? Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the chain rule for derivatives? $(-x^2)'=-2x$

Comment: The Gaussian $e^{-x^2}$ has no elementary antiderivative. Now the reason for the question in the title: the chain rule!

Comment: @Vasili Thanks, I'm really only familiar with how to utilize integrals and derivatives, not derive them, so thanks for explaining that

Comment: In the very first integral, do you really want exp(-x^2) to be the integrand, or should it be exp(-t^2) ?  (In either case I don't understand why it is "coincidentally equal to" what you wrote.)

Comment: @DanAsimov that was a mistake that lead me down the path of trying to figure out what caused my initial mistake to be an integer multiple of the derivitave

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chain rule:
$$(u \circ v)' = v' \cdot (u' \circ v)$$

Or maybe you prefer this notation:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\,u(v(x)) = v'(x) u'(v(x))$$

Now letting $u=\exp$, and noting that $\exp' = \exp$:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\,e^{v(x)} = v'(x) e^{v(x)}$$

Now letting $v:x\longmapsto -2x^2$, and noting that $v'(x) = -2x$:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\,e^{-2x^2} = -2x e^{-2x^2}$$

Comment: @user Thanks! Reading is hard. Cool username.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the definition of the derivative and some [known limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits#Sums,_products_and_composites).

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{df}{dx} &:= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h \\[2ex]
\frac{de^{-x^2}}{dx} &= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{-(x+h)^2} - e^{-x^2}}{h} \\
&= e^{-x^2} \cdot \lim_{h\to0} \frac1{e^{h^2}} \cdot \left[\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{-2xh} - 1}h + \left(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{h^2}-1}{h^2} \cdot \lim_{h\to0}  h\right)\right] \\
&= \boxed{-2x e^{-x^2}}
\end{align*}$$